# No logro que borre un registro

Tags: angular7

```
Hago lo siguiente para borrar un registro
 this.acr.deleteProductAr2(this.vararchi.indx).subscribe(() => { }, 
 (error: any) => { console.log('Borro:' + error); })

boora.service.ts

    deleteProductAr2(id:string):Observable<void> {
      if (!id) {return}

      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      let params  = new HttpParams().set('indx', id);

      return this.http.delete<void>(`${ubi}`,{params, headers}).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('Ade/id=' + id)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
    }
```

Me error 404, no entiendo por que, no logro que funcione
Gracias por la ayuda !!